# Android Studio and ADT have different TypedArray values

Tags: android, android-studio, adt

I have an app that I build with Android Studio and ADT. ADT is for others to be able to build and run. I myself use Android Studio. But recently when someone else added a custom UI control, Android Studio's version will crash in the UI that has the custom control in it. After intensive debugging, I found out it's that in Android Studio, the TypedArray of the custom control has different values than ADT's version. How does this happen? I did countless google search without success. Can someone help?

Specifically, it's the `getDimension(int index, float defValue)` that is throwing exception, the code of it is as below:

```
public float getDimension(int index, float defValue) {
    index *= AssetManager.STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
    final int[] data = mData;
    final int type = data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_TYPE];
    if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_NULL) {
        return defValue;
    } else if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
        return TypedValue.complexToDimension(
            data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA], mResources.mMetrics);
    }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't convert to dimension: type=0x"
            + Integer.toHexString(type));
}
```

You can see that it's that type of the index is not TYPE_DIMENSION. Here the issue is `mData`, which is a member of `TypedArray` class, have different value than the ADT compiled APK file at runtime. Which is very weird. The thing is that the Custom UI control is in the form of jar file, not in source code form. I guess it's something Android Studio did with the generated DEX code that caused the issue.

***Update***:
After upgrading to Android Studio 0.5.9 from Android Studio 0.5.8, the location of the exception changed slightly. Now it's `getFloat` that is throwing exception.
Below is the source code of `getFloat`

```
/**
 * Retrieve the float value for the attribute at <var>index</var>.
 * 
 * @param index Index of attribute to retrieve.
 * 
 * @return Attribute float value, or defValue if not defined..
 */
public float getFloat(int index, float defValue) {
    index *= AssetManager.STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
    final int[] data = mData;
    final int type = data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_TYPE];
    if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_NULL) {
        return defValue;
    } else if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_FLOAT) {
        return Float.intBitsToFloat(data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA]);
    } else if (type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_INT
        && type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_INT) {
        return data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA];
    }

    TypedValue v = mValue;
    if (getValueAt(index, v)) {
        Log.w(Resources.TAG, "Converting to float: " + v);
        CharSequence str = v.coerceToString();
        if (str != null) {
            return Float.parseFloat(str.toString());
        }
    }
    Log.w(Resources.TAG, "getFloat of bad type: 0x"
          + Integer.toHexString(type));
    return defValue;
}
```

The error happens at the line:

```
CharSequence str = v.coerceToString();
if (str != null) {
    return Float.parseFloat(str.toString());
}
```

Due to the incorrect `type` value caused by incorrect `mData` which is retrieved from style attributes file, the str becomes

```
@2131296258
```

instead of the correct value

```
2131296258
```

so the `parseFloat` is complaining invalid float value.

As you can see, the root cause is incorrect value for style attributes in Android Studio. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

***BTW, the ADT version worked flawless. It's only that Android Studio version crashes whenever the custom UI widget is

***Update 2:***
This question is partially answered in the form of comments. But it's not resolved. I'll leave it like this in case someone else needs information.

Comment: What is `mData`? It's hard to ascertain the cause of this problem without additional information.

Comment: This code is from Android's source code (the latest API 19). I'll update the question to include more source code

Comment: Does your jar file use or include an R class?

Comment: Yes, it includes R class. I see that from the decompiled source code

Comment: It's not my jar file. It's someone else's

Comment: That is unsupported, I'm afraid, since those ids can change to prevent collisions between two library projects. That’s why you cannot use jars for this scenario (at least you couldn't, unless something has changed).

Comment: @matiash, but why's that ADT can support this fine? I assume Android Studio supports everything ADT supports and some.

Comment: I would guess it works simply by chance, but maybe someone else can provide a more definitive response. In general you **cannot** create jars for library projects (unless they are "code-only", i.e. they contain no resources) -- see http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations

Comment: Thanks, then I'll rephrase the question. Now that I have a jar file, can I use java decompiler to recreate the project?

Comment: There is no image in this jar file

Comment: Resources do not necessarily mean images -- they can be styles, themes, layouts, animations, attributes. Basically, if there is an R file, there are resources.

Comment: I don't think I'd "assume Android Studio supports everything ADT supports and some", at least not entirely yet. It's an Early Access Preview.